# Calculating total Qty in SQL with 2 different codes ending with `396` and `400`

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that retrieves all products that has an ending
in a product code with `396` and multiple the `requiredQty * 6`.

```
SELECT p.description, SUM((requiredQty * 6)) AS singlePack 
    FROM SalesOrderLine sol 
        JOIN SalesOrder so ON sol.salesOrderID = so.id
        JOIN Product p on sol.productID = p.id
    WHERE p.code like '%396'
GROUP BY p.description
;
```

Next,

I am needing to get all codes that are ending with `400` and multiply the `requiredQty * 10`.

It would look something like this:

```
SELECT p.description, SUM((requiredQty * 10)) AS singlePack 
    FROM SalesOrderLine sol 
        JOIN SalesOrder so ON sol.salesOrderID = so.id
        JOIN Product p on sol.productID = p.id
    WHERE p.code like '%400'
GROUP BY p.description
;
```

How can I now combine the 2 values together to get total sum for each product?

This is the logic behind it.

```
requiredQty = requiredQty * 6 (Only for codes ending with `396`)

requiredQty = requiredQty * 10 (Only for codes ending with `400`)

add the 2 outputs together.


e.g.

36 = 6 * 6
50 = 5 * 10

total = 86
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT p.description,
       SUM(CASE WHEN p.code LIKE '%400' THEN requiredQty * 10
                WHEN p.code LIKE '%396' THEN requiredQty * 6
                ELSE 0
           END) AS singlePack 
FROM SalesOrderLine sol JOIN 
     SalesOrder so
     ON sol.salesOrderID = so.id JOIn
     Product p 
     ON sol.productID = p.id
WHERE p.code like '%400' OR p.code LIKE '%396'
GROUP BY p.description
```